# seaborn import as sns -> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, jupyter, seaborn, spyder

really struggling with this issue. I've tried everything in my toolbox, hoping that someone else has encountered this issue before I have who has more knowledge on this than I have. Every time I try to import seaborn as sns I get the following error:

import seaborn as sns
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    import seaborn as sns

File "C:\Users\esaeri-1122\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn__init__.py", line 6, in 
    from .rcmod import *

File "C:\Users\esaeri-1122\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 5, in 
    from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params

File "C:\Users\esaeri-1122\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 12, in 
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle

File "C:\Users\esaeri-1122\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 7, in 
    from scipy import stats

File "C:\Users\esaeri-1122\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats__init__.py", line 367, in 
    from .stats import *

File "C:\Users\esaeri-1122\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 172, in 
    import scipy.special as special

File "C:\Users\esaeri-1122\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special__init__.py", line 641, in 
    from ._ufuncs import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you used pip and conda to install packages, then that could be the cause for your problem. The solution is to reinstall Anaconda.